# Trying to find average yields TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: while-loop, typeerror, average

I am trying to find the average in a list of ages for boys and girls in Python 3.9.1 for an assignment. My code starts by defining a list for both boy and girl ages.

```
bagelist = [];
gagelist = [];
```

I then include a while loop to gather the ages and end it by trying to use the `sum() / len()` function to get the average for both lists.

```
v4 = input("enter name")

while v4 != "":
    
    v5 = input("enter sex (boy/girl) ")
    
    v6 = input("How old are they? ")
    
    if(v5 == "boy"):
        boys += 1
        bagelist.append((v6))
        
    elif(v5 == "girl"):
        girls += 1
        gagelist.append((v6))

    v4 = input("Is there anyone else to enter? If not, press ENTER.")

sum(bagelist) / len(bagelist)

sum(gagelist) / len(gagelist)
```

This just returns the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` error when I go through the program though and will not average the lists. I have tried using the `mean()` function as well by typing `statistics import mean` as well and it does not seem to want to import. I was hoping someone here would be able to tell me how to derive the mean from these lists without receiving this error.

I will say that I apologize if I am not importing the mean function quite right as I am incredibly new to Python as well as programming overall. I do also apologize if my question isn't written well as I am also  new to Stack Overflow. Constructive criticism is appreciated on these as well as the question at hand. thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: As explained in the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers), input is always read as a *string* and you need to convert it to an `int`. Also, this question was *hard to find* (hence why it went unanswered for a day) since it was not tagged with [tag:python]. Its very important to always tag with the language you are using.